# IDLE won't install, says I need to find python.msi

Tags: python

I'm having trouble installing IDLE (Python GUI).
I keep getting this problem:

[image]

Comment: Were you able to fix it? I couldn't find .msi file.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are missing that `.msi` dependency.

1. Make sure that you actually have the `python.msi` IN your downloads folder, or point to wherever you DO have this `.msi`.
2. Make sure that the `.msi` you have in the downloads folder is for version 3.3.2
3. Confirm that you have the correct version of the 3.3.2 installer (32-bit vs 64-bit).